# Event и delegate: в чем отличие?

Tags: c#, события, делегаты

Для того чтобы лучше понять хотел знать чем отличается `event` от `delegate`
и ещё применение операторов += и -= для методов в C#

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155/

Answer (score 59):

Давайте начнём с того, что `event` и `delegate` — это две разных вещи, настолько же разные, как автомобиль и морковка. Разница между *полем*-делегатом и event'ом примерно такая же, как между полем и свойством: event *иногда выглядит как* делегатное поле. Давайте разберёмся в этом.

`delegate` — это *класс*, содержащий в себе «шаблон» метода, то есть, сигнатуру метода. *Переменная* делегатного типа — объект типа [`MulticastDelegate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate) (точнее, производного от него), который может содержать один или несколько объектов, представляющих собой методы с совместимой с «шаблоном» сигнатурой (контр- и ковариантность немного усложняет картину). То есть это как бы переменная, которая может содержать *функции*. Для таких переменных определена операция `+`, которая комбинирует слагаемые-функции в одну новую функцию, и симметричная операция `-`. Эти операции автоматически порождают производные операции `+=` и `-=`.

`event` же — это просто *пара методов* в классе, обозначаемых как `add` и `remove`, и имеющих произвольную семантику, выбранную программистом. (Аналог — геттер и сеттер свойства.) В имплементации по умолчанию для event'а заводится скрытое поле делегатного типа, а add/remove добавляют или убирают из него методы (под lock'ом). (Чтобы немного запутать картину, это скрытое поле доступно по тому же имени, что и `event`.) Функции `add`/`remove`, составляющие `event`, *вызываются* соответственно как `+=` и `-=`. Никаких операций `+`/`-`, разумеется, нету.

---

Давайте ещё пробежимся по отличию event'а в классе от публичного *поля* делегатного типа.

Рассмотрим случай, когда event реализован «по умолчанию», то есть, с неявным делегатным полем. Отличие состоит в том, что:

1. Для делегатного поля у вас *полный доступ* к нему. Вы можете — также и снаружи класса! — разобрать `MulticastDelegate` на части и собрать новый, вы можете заменить его на свой или присвоить ему `null`, вы можете его вызвать, можете его скопировать себе в переменную. У вас есть полный доступ, как и к любому публичному полю. (Это, разумеется, вопиющим образом нарушает инкапсуляцию.)

   Для event'а, вы можете лишь написать `instance.Event += handler` и `instance.Event -= handler`, что отображается на функции `add` и `remove`, которые в свою очередь снова-таки вызывают `+=` и `-=` для автоматически реализованного делегата. Никакого другого доступа у вас нету. *Внутри* класса вы, однако, можете получить на чтение значение этого делегата, используя имя event'а. (Это нужно, например, для того, чтобы вызвать этот делегат; VB в отличие от C# имеет специальный метод `RaiseEvent` с нужными проверками.)
2. Ещё одно тонкое отличие (уже упомянутое в комментариях к другим ответам) состоит в том, что `add`/`remove` вызываются под lock'ом, что делает их потокобезопасными. Однако, потокобезопасность event'ов очень сложна (чуть не сказал «невозможна в принципе») (см. статью [2]), так что эта разница при правильном программировании несущественна: операции с event'ом обычно *должны* происходить лишь в одном потоке. Заметьте, что lock не доступен вне `add`/`remove`, так что вы не сможете *скопировать* делегат в локальную переменную под ним для потокобезопасного вызова*:

   ```cs
   void Raise()
   {
       EventHandler copy;
       lock (<sorry, not available>)
           copy = MyEvent;
       if (copy != null)
           copy(...);
   }
   ```

   Впрочем, в современных версиях .NET вместо `lock` используются `Intelocked`-операции, и вызов `MyEvent?.Invoke(...)` потокобезопасен.

Для случая, когда event реализуется не «по умолчанию», общего нет практически ничего. Методы `add` и `remove` могут делать всё, что угодно:

```cs
int subscriberCount = 0;
public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add { subscriberCount++; }
    remove { subscriberCount--; }
}
```

Программист *может* завести делегат самостоятельно и «складывать» туда подписанные обработчики, но это в принципе его добрая воля. С другой стороны, всё же рекомендуется не ломать ожидаемую клиентами семантику класса, и использовать event по назначению.

Литература:

1. [Jon Skeet: *Delegates and Events*](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Events)
2. [Eric Lippert: *Events and races*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/events-and-races)

---

Кроме того, ключевое слово `delegate` используется для объявления анонимной функции (более старый параллельный синтаксис для *лямбда-выражений*).

---

*В современных версиях C# для потокобезопасного вызова рекомендуется паттерн `MyEvent?.Invoke(...)`. Впрочем, с потокобезопасностью у событий не всё гладко, как объяснено в статье [2].

Comment: Для тех, кто знает делегаты: попробуйте угадать, что выведет такой код (а если не угадаете, то подумайте, почему):

    Action a1 = () => Console.Write(1);
    Action a2 = () => Console.Write(2);
    Action a3 = () => Console.Write(3);
    ((a1 + a2 + a3) - (a1 + a2))();
    ((a1 + a2 + a3) - (a1 + a3))();

Comment: Занятно. Спасибо за пример

Comment: Пример и правда интересный. А вот, что "решарпер об этом пишет": http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Delegate+subtraction+has+unpredictable+semantics

Comment: @wind: о, у них такой же пример! :-)

Насчёт «unpredictable semantics» они немного загнули. Если подписывать и отписывать один и тот же MulticastDelegate _в стековом порядке_ (первый подписался — последний отписался), всё будет работать с гарантией правильно. Если нет, возможны ошибки:

    ((a2 + (a1 + a2)) - a2) - (a1 + a2)

— не пусто. Если всё время подписывать-отписывать одиночный делегат, проблем тоже гарантировано не возникнет.

Comment: @wind: А вот что пишут о R# на [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11180128/276994):

Jon Skeet: I think it's bad of R# to call the results "unpredictable". They're very clearly specified. "Not what the user might predict" isn't in any way the same thing as "unpredictable".

supercat: It's curious that R# would warn about delegate subtraction, but not warn about the common implementations of events which have _the exact same issue_.

Comment: @VladD на самом деле,события не используют локи(начиная с C# 4.0),а более продвинутую версию класса Interlocked.CompareExchange.

Answer (score 28):

Главное отличие event от delegate состоит в том, что event может быть запущен только в классе, в котором объявлен. 
Помимо этого, при наличии event компилятор создает не только соответствующее приватное поле-делегат, но еще и два открытых метода для подписки и ее отмены на события.

Из меньших отличий стоит вспомнить о том, что событие, в отличие от делегата, может быть членом интерфейса. Это потому, что делегаты всегда являются полями, тогда как интерфейсы содержать поля не могут.
Кроме того, событие, в отличие от делегата, не может быть локальной переменной в методе.

А вообще по поводу событий и их взаимосвязи с делегатами почитайте у Рихтера, глава 11, которая так и зовется "События"

Comment: Еще стоит сказать, что методы, автоматически создаваемые компилятором для добавления и удаления обработчиков события потокобезопасны (если они не переопределены с помощью add/remove).

Comment: Хм, а что насчёт

    interface I { Action a { get; set; } }

?

Comment: Операции +=/-= для этого свойства-делегата будут выполняются без lock'а

Comment: @Shad: это да, но мы получили делегат в интерфейсе. :-)

Comment: @VladD, а я подумал, что вопрос связан со thread-safety и адресован мне :-)