# Доступ к event из вне

Tags: c#

Возможно ли дать доступ к event в другой dll?

Пример :

DC4_API.Hooks.cs

```
public static event PlayerApprovalDelegate OnPlayerApproval;
public delegate void PlayerApprovalDelegate(PlayerApprovalEvent e);
```

DC4_CORE.Call.cs

```
public static void PlayerApproval()
{
   if (DC4_API.Hooks.OnPlayerApproval != null)
   {
     DC4_API.Hooks.OnPlayerApproval(ape);
   }
}
```

Но получаю ошибку - может возможно вызвать из другой dll

```
Событие "Hooks.OnPlayerApproval" может находиться только в левой части операции += или -=
```

Comment: Если вам подошел один из предложенных ответов - пометьте его галочкой

Answer (score 2):

DLL здесь ни при чем. Событие нельзя вызвать из другого класса, можно только подписаться/отписаться, о чем и говорит ошибка.

Чтобы подписаться на событие используйте `+=`:

```
DC4_API.Hooks.OnPlayerApproval += ...метод, соответствующий PlayerApprovalDelegate
```

Для того чтобы вызвать событие извне придется изменять код в `DC4_API.Hooks.cs`, а именно создать метод, который будет его вызывать:

```
public void PerformPlayerApproval() 
{
    OnPlayerApproval(...какие-то аргументы);
}
```

затем обратиться к этому методу из `DC4_CORE.Call.cs`:

```
DC4_API.Hooks.PerformPlayerApproval();
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет.

Event'ы может вызывать только класс, который их содержит. Если вам нужно, чтобы код из другого класса отправлял event, сделайте в классе, содержащем event, публичный метод, который будет отправлять event, и который другой класс сможет вызвать.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Event и delegate: в чем отличие?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/226505/10105)